# How to let Jenkins move the new artifact to a folder?

Tags: windows, jenkins, move

I'm trying to make a post-build action, but it doesn't work.
This is my current post-build action:

```
MOVE /Y C:\Users\Lolmewn\.jenkins\jobs\Skillz\modules\Skillz$Skillz\builds\BUILD_ID\archive\Skillz\Skillz\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Skillz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar D:\BUKKIT\BUKKIT TEST\plugins\Skillz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The expected output is that it moves the newly generated Skillz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to the D: drive, but Windows (obviously) doesn't know what BUILD_ID is.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should add your friend's fix as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend fixed it for me.

```
COPY "%WORKSPACE%\target\Skillz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" "D:\BUKKIT\BUKKIT TEST\plugins\Skillz.jar" /Y
```